# Regular Expression for EDI file

Tags: java, regex, edi

I want to get a value in a edi file having below format

```
\nRJCK3:0*20180105*U*127.35
\nRJCK3:0*20180105*B*127.35
```

I want a value **U** in 1st case, which comes between 2nd & 3rd star  after `RJC*K3`, and want B in second string

Precisely, want to fetch a single character from a string, where that character will comes between 2nd & 3rd star(`*`) of a `RJC*K3`(static value).

Comment: please share what you already tried

Comment: Is that your literal text, or are the stars really placeholders for something else?

Comment: \nRJC*K3:0*20180105*U*127.35  , \nRJC*K3:0*20180105*B*127.35  This The above two are 2 usecases. I want the Alphabet "U" in 1st case, and want alphabet B in second string

Comment: You want exactly what is between the 3 stars? Is is always a capital letter?

Comment: Since EDI lines should have constant separators you can just split the line by "*" and take the item from the same index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a classic `Pattern matching` way :

```
String str1 = "\\nRJC*K3:0*20180105*U*127.35";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("RJC\\*K3.*\\*(\\w)\\*.*").matcher(str1);
String res1 = m.find() ? m.group(1) : "";
System.out.println(res1);       // U
```

---

But if there is always the same amount of `*` before the letter you want, you cn easily split and take the 3rd part :

```
String str2 = "\\nRJC*K3:0*20180105*G*127.35";
String res2 = str2.split("\\*")[3];
System.out.println(res2);        // G
```

Comment: Pattern.compile("RJC\\*K3.*\\*(\\w)\\*.*").matcher(str1); This is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to fight with edi files, you can use available libraries.

Please take a look at https://github.com/imsweb/x12-parser/

```
RJCloop.getSegment("RJC").getElementValue("RJC02")
```

can get you the value needed.