# How to add empty string when 2 delimiters one after another with String.split()

Tags: java, regex, data-processing, edifact

I'm quite new to regex and I have to split EDI files for a loader I'm developing. If you are not familiar with it, here is an example of 2 segments (modified to explain all so it's not a real example):

```
APD+EM2:0:16?'30::6+++++++DA'APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'
```

End of lines are marked with `'` and I ignore if there's an escaping char which is the question mark - `?'` is to ignore for example for the end of a line. `\+` and `:` are the main delimiters (when data are composite like an address).

The split for the segments works fine, but I have issues with the other delimiters. I would like to have a `String[]` with all the elements, even if they are empty, because I need to process it after (insert in DB). With the example above, I would like to have a tab like this:

```
APD+EM2:0:16?'30::6+++++++DA
```

would transform into:

```
{"APD","EM2","0","16?'30","","6","","","","","","","DA"}
```

Currently with my code, I get a tab like this:

```
{"APD","EM2","0","16?'30","6","DA"}
```

Can I please have some help with my regex? Making it match `++` and `::` is beyond my skills for now. I need to remove the escaping characters as well, but I'll work on that on my own.

BTW, I need to process a lot of data - 300gb of raw text - so if what I do is bad performance-wise, don't hesitate to tell me - like per example split with both `+` and `:` at the same time.

The EDIFACT format is not something discussed a lot around here, and the few examples I found were not working for me.

Current code:

```
private final String DATA_ELEMENT_DELIMITER = "(?<!\\?)\\+";
private final String DATA_COMPOSITE_ELEMENT_DELIMITER = "(?<!\\?):";

private String[] split (String segments){       
    return Stream.of(segments)
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile(DATA_ELEMENT_DELIMITER)::splitAsStream)
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile(DATA_COMPOSITE_ELEMENT_DELIMITER)::splitAsStream)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

---

EDIT :
The code I'm running - BTW, I'm running on Java 8, not sure it makes a difference though:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public class Split {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Split s = new Split();
        System.out.println(
                Arrays.toString(
                    s.split("APD+EM2:0:16?'30::6+++++++DA'")
                )
            );
    }
    
    
    private static final Pattern DATA_ELEMENT_DELIMITER = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\?)\\+");
    private static final Pattern DATA_COMPOSITE_ELEMENT_DELIMITER = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\?):");
    
    private String[] split (String segments){       
        return Stream.of(segments)
                .flatMap(DATA_ELEMENT_DELIMITER::splitAsStream)
                .flatMap(DATA_COMPOSITE_ELEMENT_DELIMITER::splitAsStream)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

Here is the output i get :

```
[APD, EM2, 0, 16?'30, , 6, DA']
```

---

EDIT EDIT

After trying to run this code in an online Java 11 compiler, the output is correct, but not on Java 8.

Comment: In general, I'd recommend not to use regular expressions for parsing Edifact document unlses you can ensure that your character set does not use (variable-length) multi-byte encodings such as `UNOX`, `UNOY` or `KECA` i.e. If you stll want to make use of regular expressions the whole expression can become pretty unreadable quickly as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111632/regular-expression-for-edi-file) and [that](https://mycsharp.de/forum/threads/105437/geloest-komplexes-regex-in-bezug-auf-edi?page=1#forumpost-3727017) sample showcase

Comment: not clear what the problem is, feeding `"APD+EM2:0:16?'30::6+++++++DA"`  into your code is returning `[APD, EM2, 0, 16?'30, , 6, , , , , , , DA]` ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/BgsMuj))

Comment: @Roman what would you recommend then ? frameworks ?
 user15244370 well ... on my side it's not what is happening haha

Comment: I'm currently working on a Java-native Edifact parser that might be open-sourced when it is ready (depends on my employee). It is basically just a port with enhancement of the [node-edifact](https://github.com/tdecaluwe/node-edifact) or [ts-edifact](https://github.com/RovoMe/ts-edifact) library. Both of them do not really support multi-byte encodings unfortunately for now. Until then the best choices might be Smooks and X12 as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794262/how-go-i-parse-edifact-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Does your project have a name so i can check in the future what it becomes and maybe integrate it in my project(s) ?
I have issues using libraries to read / parse edifact as the one i receive does not follow standard format like X12, it's just raw data :/ I tried using StAEDI 1st but i have no UNA or UNB in my EDI so doesn't want to read and i didn't try but i guess it'll be the same for other frameworks - As of now regex is my way to go because of this reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first note is that for improved performance, you definitely want to compile the `Pattern`s once and reuse the instance:

```java
private static final Pattern DATA_ELEMENT_DELIMITER = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\?)\\+");
private static final Pattern DATA_COMPOSITE_ELEMENT_DELIMITER = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\?):");
// ...
.flatMap(DATA_ELEMENT_DELIMITER::splitAsStream)
.flatMap(DATA_COMPOSITE_ELEMENT_DELIMITER::splitAsStream)
```

---

Second, as @user15244370 mentioned, running your code **does** produce the output you are looking for. I ran it like this:

```java
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        split("APD+EM2:0:16?'30::6+++++++DA'APD+EM2:0:1630::6+++++++DA'")
    )
);
```

and got the output:

```
[APD, EM2, 0, 16?'30, , 6, , , , , , , DA'APD, EM2, 0, 1630, , 6, , , , , , , DA']
```

---

Assuming there is some difference between what you have posted and what you are actually running, the documentation for [splitAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence)) mentions:

> Trailing empty strings will be discarded and not encountered in the stream.

---

Are you doing any additional processing after the call to `split`? And how are you printing the array? Is it possible that the method you are using to print the `string[]` may be removing empty strings? As far as I can tell, your implementation should function as you intend.

Comment: Thanks for the the compile, sure will be better to compile once each than every time
I tried to move it outside of the class i wanted to be sure nothing else interfers with my code. I added the code i'm using on original post